# List being recognized as tuple

Tags: python

My code, explains that this is a list. But somehow, the system is giving me a exception:

```
TypeError: 'tuple' object doesn't support item deletion
```

My code explains this with:

```
x = (insert a tuple elements here)
x = list(x)
```

My code is this (I'm progamming a code that will recognize a number expression. This and more in [this lib.](https://github.com/CaioFrancisco/Mathy))

```
def num_expression(*nums):
    nums = list(nums)


    if '*' in nums:
        numsam = nums
        search = __charposition(numsam,'*')
        nums2 = 0
        nums3 = 0
        for i in search:
            num2 = i - 1
            num3 = i + 1
            del numsam[i]
            num4 = numsam[num2]*numsam[num3]
            syn = i - 1
            del numsam[syn]
            numsam[i] = num4
    if '/' in nums:
        numsam = nums
        search = __charposition(numsam,'/')
        nums2 = 0
        nums3 = 0
        for i in search:
            num2 = i - 1
            num3 = i + 1
            del numsam[i]
            num4 = numsam[num2]/numsam[num3]
            syn = i - 1
            del numsam[syn]
            numsam[i] = num4
    excptd_vari = 1
    pos = 0
    num = 0
    syn1 = ''
    syn2 = ''
    syn3 = ''
    syn4 = ''
    size = len(nums)

    for i in nums:

        if expctd_vari == 1 and isinstance(i, int):
            syn1 = i
            expctd_vari = 2
            num1syn = True
        elif expctd_vari == 2 and isinstance(i, str):
            syn2 = i
            expctd_vari = 3

        elif expctd_vari == 3 and isinstance(i, int):
            expctd_vari = 2
            if num1syn == True:
                syn3 = i
                if syn2 == '+':
                    num+= syn1+syn3
                if syn2 == '-':
                    num-= syn1+syn3
                else:
                    raise SyntaxError
                num1syn = False
            else:
                syn4 = i
                if syn2 == '+':
                    num+= syn3+syn4
                if syn2 == '-':
                    num-= syn3+syn4
        else:
            raise SyntaxError

def __charposition(string, char):
    pos = [] 
    for n in range(len(string)):
        if string[n] == char:
            pos.append(n)
    return pos
```

Observation: I'm fixing divider problem too. It's just add an return in the final.

Comment: Please don't put complete code blindly, try to provide minimal code possibly with error you are getting.... Provide user input and expected result as well

Comment: You're making us guess where the error happens, and you're making us guess how this code is called.  Please edit the question to include the full error traceback message, and an example of how you call the code.

Comment: doesn't make sense. I can see 4 'del numsam[I]', that's probably the only place you may get this error assuming it's a tuple. since you do 'list' conversion, that's not possible.

Comment: @user3713719 I did the convertion! See the begginning of the function

Comment: can you please add complete output including the command you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem may be the line:

```
def num_expression(*nums):
```

When I check the provided argument nums I get `((4, 5, 6),)` and after converting to a list it's `[(4, 5, 6)]`.

Try changing the line to:

```
def num_expression(nums):
```

Comment: The error indicates that you somewhere are trying to delete an item from a tuple. The only place I can fint that tries to delete something from something is `del numsam[syn]` but `numsam = nums` and `nums = list(nums)`. The only way I have been able to reproduce the error is if the argument to the function `num_expression()` is a tuple, which gives the result I described above. Try to print `nums` on the first line of the function to see what it looks like.